# pyarrow - identify the fragments written or filters used when writing a parquet dataset?

Tags: dask, pyarrow

My use case is that I want to pass the file paths or filters to a task in Airflow as an xcom so that my next task can read the data which was just processed.

Task A writes a table to a partitioned dataset and a number of Parquet file fragments are generated --> Task B reads those fragments later as a dataset. I need to only read relevant data though, not the entire dataset which could have many millions of rows.

I have tested two approaches:

1. List modified files right after I finish writing to the dataset. This will provide me with a list of paths which I can call ds.dataset(paths) on during my next task. I can use `partitioning.parse()` on these paths or check the fragments to get a list of filters used (`frag.partition_expression`)

A flaw with this is that I can have files being written in parallel to the same dataset.

2. I can generate the filters used when writing the dataset by turning the table into a pandas dataframe, doing a groupby, and then constructing filters. I am not sure if there is a simpler approach to this. I can then use pq._filters_to_expression() on the results to create a usable filter.

This is not ideal since I need to fix certain data types which do not get saved properly as an Airflow xcom (no pickling so everything has to be in json format). Also, if I want to partition on a dictionary column, I might need to tweak this function.

```
    def create_filter_list(df, partition_columns):
        """Creates a list of pyarrow filters to be sent through an xcom and evaluated as an expression. Xcom disables pickling, so we need to save timestamp and date values as strings and convert downstream"""
        filter_list = []
        value_list = []
        partition_keys = [df[col] for col in partition_columns]
        for keys, _ in df[partition_columns].groupby(partition_keys):
            if len(partition_columns) == 1:
                if is_jsonable(keys):
                    value_list.append(keys)
                elif keys is not None:
                    value_list.append(str(keys))
            else:
                if not isinstance(keys, tuple):
                    keys = (keys,)
                read_filter = []
                for name, val in zip(partition_columns, keys):
                    if type(val) == np.int_:
                        read_filter.append((name, "==", int(val)))
                    elif val is not None:
                        read_filter.append((name, "==", str(val)))
                filter_list.append(read_filter)
        if len(partition_columns) == 1:
            if len(value_list) > 0:
                filter_list = [(name, "in", value_list) for name in partition_columns]
        return filter_list
```

Any suggestions on which approach I should take, or if there is a better way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can watch this issue (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-10440) which does what you want I believe.  In the meantime, you could use `basename_template` as a workaround.

```
import glob
import os

import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.dataset as pads

class TrackingWriter:

    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 0
        part_schema = pa.schema({'part': pa.int64()})
        self.partitioning = pads.HivePartitioning(part_schema)

    def next_counter(self):
        result = self.counter
        self.counter += 1
        return result

    def write_dataset(self, table, base_dir):
        counter = self.next_counter()
        pads.write_dataset(table, base_dir, format='parquet', partitioning=self.partitioning, basename_template=f'batch-{counter}-part-{{i}}')
        files_written = glob.glob(os.path.join(base_dir, '**', f'batch-{counter}-*'))
        return files_written

table_one = pa.table({'part': [0, 0, 1, 1], 'val': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
table_two = pa.table({'part': [0, 0, 1, 1], 'val': [5, 6, 7, 8]})

writer = TrackingWriter()
print(writer.write_dataset(table_one, '/tmp/mydataset'))
print(writer.write_dataset(table_two, '/tmp/mydataset'))
```

This is just a rough sketch.  You'd probably also want code to run at startup to see what the next free value of `counter` is.  Or you could use a `uuid` instead of a counter.

Comment: Nice, so I swapped os with adlfs and "batch-{counter}" with the "{task_id}-{execution}" from Airflow which names each file based on the unique schedule (this is nice because I can load data into the same dataset in parallel and can use glob to find the files I want).

Comment: So some of my datasets are written using pq.write_to_dataset as well (sometimes I want to repartition data into a single parquet file based on the partition_filename_cb function). There was no basename_template so my work around was using the metadata_collector when writing the dataset: files.append(fs.sep.join([root_path, piece.row_group(0).column(0).file_path]))

This seems fairly convenient and does not require me to list blobs. I am using your method for ds.write_dataset() datasets though - hopefully I can have a standard approach someday.

Comment: Cool - this worked fine for me, thanks a lot - I don't think I would have gone down this path without you. Since I am passing file paths, I can generate a dataset with them and then use fragment.partition_expression to generate a list of filter expressions ultimately... kind of a lot of work, but it does what I intended

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion (not sure if this is optimal for your use case or not):

The key problem is the need to correctly select subset of the data, this can be 'fixed' upstream.  The function/script that updates the big dataframe can contain a condition to save a temporary copy of data that is modified and satisfies some requirements in a separate (temporary) path. Then this file would be passed to the downstream tasks, which can delete the temporary file once it's processed.